# How to move (and overwrite) all files from one directory to another?

Tags: linux, unix

I know of the `mv` command to move a file from one place to another, but how do I move all files from one directory into another (that has a bunch of other files), overwriting if the file already exists?

Comment: beg yours, I was mixing it up with rm for some reason. Need coffee.

Comment: I know this is old question, but what about "rsync -az src/ dest/" it will copy all files which do not exist in dest/ directory from src/, and then just remove destination directory with "rm -rf dest/"

Answer (score 25, accepted):

It's just `mv srcdir/* targetdir/`.

If there are too many files in `srcdir` you might want to try something like the following approach:

```
cd srcdir
find -exec mv {} targetdir/ +
```

In contrast to `\;` the final `+` collects arguments in an `xargs` like manner instead of executing `mv` once for every file.

Comment: just a note: on directories with a couple of thousands files, you wont be able to use the * since the argument list will be too long for the shell to handle, so you would need to use "find" instead or similar solution

Comment: I've tried the following command "find . -exec mv {} ../clean-copy/Ressources/img/ +" but got the following error : "find: -exec: no terminating ";" or "+"" - Any idea why ?

Comment: @musiKk Thanks for the tip. Although my comment is a question, it's here because I feel the answer is 99% helping but missing the 1% that would make it perfect.

Comment: @DirtyHenry you might need to use `\+` rather than just `+`

Comment: Are these solution recursion-safe? I managed to blow-up filesystem on older Solaris 15-ish years ago by moving a/* to a/b. mv wasn't smart enough to prevent infinite dir tree a/b/b/b/b/b/b/b/b/b/...

Comment: Is this still valid syntax? I get:  `find -exec mv {} /home/kahuna/full/path/to/folder/json/Prod223_2670/ +`
find: missing argument to `-exec'

Comment: As others have suggested, maybe escaping like `\+` works? Maybe it depends on the shell? I always used bash but I successfully tested in zsh and csh as well just now. So unfortunately don't know.

Answer (score 62):

```
mv -f source target
```

From the man page:

```
-f, --force
          do not prompt before overwriting
```

Comment: `mv -f /a/b /c/d` moves `b` inside `d` (so I have `/c/d/a`) instead of overwriting `d` with `a` (I want `/c/a`). How can I do such overwrite?

Comment: @Xenos you would need to delete the file `d` before you can create a directory `d`. That would require a couple of commands, there's no force overwrite of a directory with a file that I know of. You could script that with just a few lines, but it would be better taken up as a separate question since it deviates from question the OPasked.

Answer (score 19):

It's also possible by using `rsync`, for example:

```
rsync -a src/ dst/
```

where:

- `-a`, `--archive`:               archive mode; equals `-rlptgoD` (no `-H,-A,-X`)

Optionally you can add the following:

- `-v`, `--verbose`:               increase verbosity
- `--delete-after`: delete files on the receiving side after the transfer has completed. This makes it a `mv` instead of a `cp`, but be aware that this will remove files that are present in the `dst/` directory. Check [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/156664/what-are-the-differences-between-the-rsync-delete-options) for details on the different `delete`-options.

Prefix with `sudo` to override potential permission issues. Be aware of what you're doing when using `rsync` within the root filesystem.

Comment: deleted all my data... even at dest

Comment: yup, just lost all my files. Shame on me for thinking people online know what they are talking about.

Comment: I edited the comment to not be as dangerous anymore.

Answer (score 15):

For moving and overwriting files, it doesn't look like there is the `-R` option (when in doubt check your options by typing `[your_cmd] --help`. Also, this answer depends on how you want to move your file. Move all files, files & directories, replace files at destination, etc.

When you type in `mv --help` it returns the description of all options.

For mv, the syntax is `mv [option] [file_source] [file_destination]`

To move simple files: `mv image.jpg folder/image.jpg`

To move as folder into destination `mv folder home/folder`

To move all files in source to destination `mv folder/* home/folder/`

Use `-v` if you want to see what is being done: `mv -v`

Use `-i` to prompt before overwriting: `mv -i`

Use `-u` to update files in destination. It will only move source files newer than the file in the destination, and when it doesn't exist yet: `mv -u`

Tie options together like `mv -viu`, etc.

Answer (score 2):

If you simply need to answer "y" to all the overwrite prompts, try this:

```
y | mv srcdir/* targetdir/
```

Comment: Didn't work for me (RHEL9) - throw up error and denied all directories and files without newlines:  `root@host:[/opt/wwwdata/html/kirwiki]:# y | mv extensions/new-directory/* extensions/old-directory/
-bash: y: command not found
mv: overwrite 'extensions/old-directory/bin'? mv: overwrite 'extensions/old-directory/modules'? mv: overwrite 'extensions/old-directory/screenshots'? mv: overwrite 'extensions/old-directory/tests'? root@host:[/opt/wwwdata/html/kirwiki]:#
`

what did help:
`alias cp='cp' `
`cp -arvp new-directory old-directory`

Answer (score 1):

In linux shell, many commands accept multiple parameters and therefore could be used with wild cards. So, for example if you want to move all files from folder A to folder B, you write:

```
mv A/* B
```

If you want to move all files with a certain "look" to it, you could do like this:

```
mv A/*.txt B
```

Which copies all files that are blablabla.txt to folder B

Star (*) can substitute any number of characters or letters while ? can substitute one. For example if you have many files in the shape file_number.ext and you want to move only the ones that have two digit numbers, you could use a command like this:

```
mv A/file_??.ext B
```

Or more complicated examples:

```
mv A/fi*_??.e* B
```

For files that look like fi<-something->_<-two characters->.e<-something->

Unlike many commands in shell that require -R to (for example) copy or remove subfolders, mv does that itself.

Remember that mv overwrites without asking (unless the files being overwritten are read only or you don't have permission) so make sure you don't lose anything in the process.

For your future information, if you have subfolders that you want to copy, you could use the -R option, saying you want to do the command recursively. So it would look something like this:

```
cp A/* B -R
```

By the way, all I said works with rm (remove, delete) and cp (copy) too and beware, because once you delete, there is no turning back! Avoid commands like `rm * -R` unless you are sure what you are doing.

Comment: The `-R` flag must come before the glob.

Comment: This is technically incorrect: “In linux shell, many commands accept parameters with wild cards.” Wildcard expansion has nothing to do with the command, as it is a function of the shell and occurs before the command is ever called. No command does its own wildcard expansion, and therefore it is wrong to say that they accept wildcards.

Comment: @tchrist thanks for clarifying this, I wasn't always sure whether that was shell's doing or the program. However, it's still not without merit to mention that, because at least it would be understood that rm, cp, mv and like I said, many shell commands accept multiple files to remove or copy.

Comment: @musiKk According to the man pages yes, but any linux at least that I have worked with accepts the options (`-R` at least) anywhere in the command; before the sources, between the sources and destination and after destination. I even tested it right now with .exe files provided with MinGW (in Windows) enabling some of the shell commands of Linux in Windows and they also have the same behavior

Comment: @Shahbaz: You're right. This is a disturbing realization. I still think it is bad practice to promote usage that goes against the manual. Who knows how portable that behavior is.

Comment: @musiKk: From `info coreutils 'note Common Options'`: Normally options and operands can appear in any order, and programs act as if all the options appear before any operands.  For example, `sort -r passwd -t :` acts like `sort -r -t : passwd`, since `:` is an option-argument of `-t`.  However, if the `POSIXLY_CORRECT` environment variable is set, options must appear before operands, unless otherwise specified for a particular command.